# Wrong value being returned "HASH(0x8dc0f54)"

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm trying to get a value returned to `$HTMLData` but I get `HASH(0x8dc0f54)` return instead of `Hello World` I cant seem to figure it out.

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my $XML = new XML::Simple;
my $Data = $XML->XMLin("Data/Content/$PageName.xml");

my $HTMLData = $Data->{HTMLData};

print "$HTMLData";
```

XML DATA:

```
<HTMLData>

<p>Hello World</p>

</HTMLData>
```

Comment: Try `$Data->{HTMLData}->{p}`. You can `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($Data);` to view the data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dumped out the actual data you'd see what was happening here:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($HTMLData);
#$VAR1 = {
#          'p' => 'Hello World'
#        };
```

You aren't accessing the "p" node. Try `my $HTMLData = $Data->{'HTMLData'}->{'p'};`.

Comment: Not looking to access the "p" node need to access HTMLData and get the HTML data "<p>Hello World</p>" in that node

Comment: Then reencode it: `print $XML->XMLOut($HTMLData);` You stated you wanted the content 'Hello World' in your question.

Comment: @Bill then the XML is wrong. If the content of the node is HTML then it should be enclosed in a CDATA block